# Представляет опасность или несет опасность?

Tags: грамотная-речь, стилистика

Равноправны ли эти два выражения? Можно сказать, что кто-то представляет опасность или лучше все-таки "несет"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В словарях встречаются оба варианта.  Здесь, мне кажется, надо смотреть контекст. Например, Разъяренный медведь представляет опасность для человека. ("Несет" будет звучать некрасиво, отвлекает второе значение).  А в варианте: Встреча с медведем несет опасность для человека (возможны оба варианта, равнозначны). 
Как предположение - возможно, что выражение "несет опасность" грамотнее употреблять с неодушевленными существительными.

Answer (score 2):

Субъект опасность представляет - Этот убийца представляет опасность для общества.

Объект опасность с собой несёт - Зима несёт с собой опасность обморожения.